# Why app.intent throws error (malformed response) in actions-on-google

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am adding a basic card to my action, and, when testing in simulator, the error `Malformed response, final_response must be set`

Here is the webhook:

```
app.intent('Selected subjects', (conv, {Subject}) => {
subject = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || Subject;
if (!conv.screen) {
conv.close(subjectCard[Subject].text);
} else {
conv.close(`Maybe this would help`, new BasicCard(subjectCard[Subject]));
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who occurs a problem in this, with firebase, go to Functions, then Health. This will depict the exact line and code which is an error. For example, in this one, the word "subject" is not marked as a var, thus resulting in an error. I would recommend using firebase, as the Firebase console would depict errors that are not shown on the terminal/ cmd/ command line etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. First, you must do either `conv.close` or `conv.ask` in your intent handler. In your code, it looks like your function does neither when `conv.screen` is true. To fix it, change the else-clause to:

```
else {
  conv.close(new BasicCard(...));
}
```

The second problem was that you didn't instantiate `BasicCard`, which is fixed in my snippet above.

This is a very common error, and I'd recommend reading [Debugging Common Actions on Google Errors](https://medium.com/google-developers/debugging-common-actions-on-google-errors-7c8527378d27) for tips and tricks on how to debug.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add in all the code. I've edited it now